# Yii Crsf works fine but it affects language changing

Tags: php, yii

I am developing a Yii project and am new to Yii framework. I was following the steps of how to use Yii to send a POST request using Crsf.

I used the following code in config/main.php...

```
'components'=>array(
    'request'=>array(
        'enableCsrfValidation'=>true,
    ),
),
```

After that, it works fine and can successfully write data to DB; however, it affects the language changing of my site. When I remove the crsf code from main.php, the language can be changed. If anyone knows how to put crsf code and not affecting the language?

Comment: how do you change your language?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour yii originally hv own function to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config/main.php

```
'components'=>array(
   'request'=>array(
       'enableCsrfValidation'=>false,
   ),
),
```

Then for those php have csrf form add the code below:

```
<?php Yii::app()->request->enableCsrfValidation = true; ?>
```

Suddenly have this idea to solved =D